# no suitable method found for create() method reactor.test.StepVerifier.create

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, junit5

I am trying to perform reactive repository test however even compiler do not throw any error in code editor code won't compile. Why is that?

```
Error:(52, 21) java: no suitable method found for create(com.geborskimateusz.microservices.core.recommendation.persistence.RecommendationEntity)
method reactor.test.StepVerifier.<T>create(org.reactivestreams.Publisher<? extends T>) is not applicable(inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s) inferred: com.geborskimateusz.microservices.core.recommendation.persistence.RecommendationEntity
upper bound(s): org.reactivestreams.Publisher<? extends java.lang.Object>,com.geborskimateusz.microservices.core.recommendation.persistence.RecommendationEntity)method reactor.test.StepVerifier.<T>create(org.reactivestreams.Publisher<? extends T>,long) is not applicable(cannot infer type-variable(s) T
            (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
        method reactor.test.StepVerifier.<T>create(org.reactivestreams.Publisher<? extends T>,reactor.test.StepVerifierOptions) is not applicable
          (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
            (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
@Test
void create() {
    recommendationRepository.deleteAll();

    RecommendationEntity given = RecommendationEntity.builder()
            .recommendationId(BASE_RECOMMENDATION_ID)
            .movieId(BASE_MOVIE_ID)
            .content("Fake recommendation")
            .build();

    StepVerifier.create(recommendationRepository.save(given))
            .expectNextMatches(recommendationEntity -> assertRecommendation(given, recommendationEntity))
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

And repository looks like this:

```
public interface RecommendationRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<RecommendationEntity, String> {
    Flux<RecommendationEntity> findByMovieId(int movieId);
}
```

Comment: can you please post your `RecommendationEntity.class` my guess is that the entity is not containing a default constructor or something like that, are you using Lombok?

Comment: Hi, This was actually build issue.